# Character of representation of quotient group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Suppose we know both the character of a representation (e.g. the adjoint) of a lie group $\mathrm{G}$ and that of a representation of a discrete group $\Gamma$, let us call them $\chi(G)$ and $\chi(\Gamma)$. Is it possible to derive from them the character of a representation of the quotient group $\mathrm{G/\Gamma}$, i.e. $\chi(\mathrm{G/\Gamma})$? If yes, how?

Comment: If there is no relation between the rep of G and the rep of $\Gamma$, there is no way to construct a rep of the quotient (and $\Gamma$ should at the very least be a normal subgroup, so that the qquestion at least  makes sense!...)